# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework - Linq query with order by

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

[image: issue_line_person table]

I have data table call `issue_line_person` (*above picture*). I want to retrieve set of rows which are equal to specific `line_id` and `issue_id`, with ascending order according to the `levelOfResponsibility`.

This is the SQL query for that.

```
SELECT * 
FROM issue_line_person 
WHERE line_id = " + line_line_id + " AND issue_id = " + issueId + " 
ORDER BY levelOfResponsibility
```

How to do that using Entity Framework and a Linq method?

Comment: A good start would be to show your Entity Framework model. We have no idea at which stage of the process you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an entity "Issue_Line_Person" in your EF model without properties in child entities.

```
var result = Issue_Line_Person.Where(_=>_.line_id == LINEID && _.issue_id == ISSUEID).OrderBy(_=>_.levelOfResponsibility).ToList()
```